# How to avoid with css when background of the second line covers the letters of the first line?

Tags: css

I am building this site: http://alpha.beta.us.lt/

You can see that background of

element in title of the second line covers the first line. How to avoid this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the `line-height` property

Make the following changes in your code.

```
.title2 {
   line-height: 2; /* 35px works perfect in your case */
}
```

Comment: @user1016695, Since you are pretty new. After a solution works, always make a habit of accepting the answer. Tq :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line-height property.

Example:

```
line-height:40px
```